# Invoke a ribbon action programmatically

Tags: excel, vsto

Is it possible to invoke an action associated with a button on a ribbon tab? (That ribbon tab belongs to another Excel addin, i.e. it's not Excel's builtin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused, can't you just call the method that handles the event? E.g.

```
someRibbonButton_Clicked(null, null);
```

---

EDIT: 
Ah, it's for another plugin. You can send the shortcut key to Excel.

For example, if you send Alt,N,T to excel it will run the "Insert Table" command. You can do it from code like so:

```
_excelApplication.SendKeys("%", true);
_excelApplication.SendKeys("n", true);
_excelApplication.SendKeys("t", true);
```

SendKeys docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx).

The "%" sign means "Alt".

You can see which letters you need if you press Alt in Excel. It will show tooltips for each button showing you the correct shortcut key you need to send.

It works for built-in buttons as well as for plugin buttons.

Comment: I can't call a method of an unknown addin as the name of that method is unknown and it's in a different app domain.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you wanted to do it for another plugin. I've edited my answer for that scenario.

Comment: What if shortcuts aren't assigned for that addin? (As far as I remember clicking Office toolbar buttons programmatically was extermely easy before ribbon was introduced)

Comment: I think they're always assigned. I'm not sure how reliable this is on different machines, though, maybe the same plugin might get a different shortcut assigned on a different machine. I'd suggest trying it out on a couple of machines. Might not be the prettiest solution, but I don't think there's a way to get programmatic access to another plugin's ribbon.